# Upload a pdf from a url into Firestore storage bucket (Node JS)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am making a get request (using axios) to a pdf hosted at a url endpoint, which is returning an encoded stream as show below:

```
'%PDF-1.4\n%����\n1 0 obj\n<</Creator (Chromium)\n/Producer (Skia/PDF m78)\n/CreationDate (D:20211115122641+00\'00\')\n/ModDate (D:20211115122641+00\'00\')>>\nendobj\n3 0 obj\n<</ca 1\n/BM /Normal>>\nendobj\n4 0 obj\n<</Type /XObject\n/Subtype /Image\n/Width 1245\n/Height 249\n/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB\n/BitsPerComponent 8\n/Filter /DCTDecode\n/ColorTransform 0\n/Length 35434>> stream\n����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000��\u0002(ICC_PROFILE\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0018\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0010\u0000\u0000mntrRGB XYZ
```

I am then uploading this to our storage bucket using the following:

```
const file = bucket.file(path);
const fileOptions = {contentType: 'application/pdf'};
return file.save(data, fileOptions)
    .then(() => {
        return {
            url: file.getSignedUrl({action: 'read', expires: expiryDate}),
            path
        }
    });
```

However the URL returned, when opened just displays a blank PDF (containing the correct number of pages) but without any content.

What is the best way for downloading and uploading a PDF from a url into storage? Would it be this approach (though i am not sure what i am missing), or is there a way to upload the URL I have to storage directly?

Comment: To better @Mousumi's response, can you please answer the below questions:  
**1.** Are you able to view the uploaded file successfully using the URL from Cloud Console?  
**2.** Is the “Type” property for the uploaded pdf showing as “application/pdf” in the Cloud Console?

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete. Can you share the entire code?

Answer (score -1):

The code that you are using sets the content type as ‘application/pdf’. However, it is unclear how you are downloading the object from the storage that could have caused this behaviour.

```
const file = bucket.file(path);
const fileOptions = {contentType: 'application/pdf'};
return file.save(data, fileOptions)
```

In general,**File.createWriteStream()** method is used to **upload arbitrary data to a file**. The details about this can be referred to from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/storage/file#_google_cloud_storage_File_save_member_1_).

Also, you could use **Multer** to upload files from a function. Multer is a node.js middleware for handling multipart/form-data, which is primarily used for uploading files.  Multer adds a body object and a file or files object to the request object. The body object contains the values of the text fields of the form, the file or files object contains the files uploaded via the form. You can also refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage) for more information on Multer.